# Как настроить подключение к БД не глобально, а отдельно для нужных bot.message.handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Имеется 2 функции которые должны быть подключены к БД для разных действий, когда подключение глобальное работает только первая функция, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в фк-ции plus. Вот исправленная версия:

```
def plus(self, users_id: int, amount: int) -> None:
    self.cursor.execute(
        'UPDATE `records` SET `balance` = `balance` + ? WHERE `users_id` = ?',
        (amount, users_id)
    )
    self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это использовать, так как у меня все функции БД в отдельном классе(BotsBD), а вызов и конект происходит через BotsBD = BotsBD('accountant.db'), можно ли решить проблему не переписывая пол кода?

Comment: Можете дать код вашего класса?) Появляется ли ошибка, если вы один раз в начале кода создадите объект бд (BotsBD в вашем случае), и потом бедете его использовать, если да, то какая? Если ошибок нет - скорее всего что-то с вашими sql-запросами

Comment: https://nekobin.com/cobozumite - код модуля с БД. Ошибок нету при запуске и эксплуатации мейна, просто не передаются данные.  https://nekobin.com/mipufenepa - это код самой функции, которая должна передавать инфу. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Ошибка в запросе, сейчас напишу ответом

Comment: Все, по идее должно сработать)

Comment: Не думаю что именно там была ошибка, всё равно не передаёт, может всё-таки проблема в конекте?

Comment: У вас в базе были аргументы местами перепутаны, посмотрите базу в редакторе, есть ли там вообще какие-либо записи?

Comment: В таблице у меня по порядку: id(из таблицы users), users_id, balance, date. Записи не добавляются никакие, как будто нету конекта и при этом ошибки тоже(

Comment: А можете дать файл бд? Вы как, кстати, скрипт запускаете? Через консоль? Если да, убедитесь что вы находитесь в папке со скриптом, а я бы запускал даблкликом, еслы вы на винде

Comment: Добавил фотографии структуры БД, работаю с макОС поэтому запускаю через терминал PyCharm, и запускается весь скрипт, часть с добавлением пользователя в таблицу 'users' работает, а вот 'records' нет, уже неделю ищу решение(